# Python random colors flickering on object

Tags: python, random, colors

The following function defines rectangles, their x/y location, width and height, and color. I would like the color to be randomly chosen *every time*.

```
def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    rand_color = (random.randrange(0,255),random.randrange(0,255),random.randrange(0,255))
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, rand_color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])
```

The current code is causing the program to flicker through every different color. Even if I change the rand_color to a variation of choosing between black and white, the rectangle flickers between black and white. What's happening here?

Comment: The function does select a different color each time it's called. Are you calling `things()` inside a pygame display update loop? That would make the colors flicker. You might also what to use `randrange(0, 256)` to get the full range of legal values (or use `randint(0, 255)`).

Comment: @martineau, hi, yes these things() are within an update loop. It looks like it flickers between several hundred colors a second however

The update looks looks like

`def game_loop()
   ...
   things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, rand_color)
        thing_starty += thing_speed
   ...
   pygame.display.update()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment, your function generates a different color each time it's called and the flickering problem is probably a result of calling it too often. You could probably fix that by making `rand_color` a global and define its value outside the function before it's ever called.

However I think the idea in [John Rodger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31486997/355230) of using a class is a good one, but would implement it differently and try to take advantage of object-oriented programming instead of reinventing the whole wheel. Below is a runnable example of what I mean. Every time you run it, it will generate a randomly colored rectangle to represent a `Thing` object, and this color will not change or flicker as the display's updated.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import random

FPS = 30  # frames per second
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

class Thing(pygame.Rect):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Thing, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # init Rect base class
        # define additional attributes
        self.color = tuple(random.randrange(0, 256) for _ in range(3))
        self.x_speed, self.y_speed = 5, 5  # how fast it moves

    def draw(self, surface, width=0):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, self, width)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    fpsclock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(250)  # enable keyboard repeat for held down keys
    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((500,400), 0,32)
    gameDisplay.fill(WHITE)

    thingx,thingy, thingw,thingh = 200,150, 100,50
    thing = Thing(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh)  # create an instance

    while True:  # display update loop
        gameDisplay.fill(WHITE)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    thing.y += thing.y_speed
                elif event.key == K_UP:
                    thing.y -= thing.y_speed
                elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    thing.x += thing.x_speed
                elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                    thing.x -= thing.x_speed

        thing.draw(gameDisplay)  # display at current position
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsclock.tick(FPS)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

With what code you posted, the best answer you can get is that rand_color is being reevaluated every time the loop is iterated, causing a different color to be assigned.

My suggestion is to only call the random function when you initialize the thing, and that the thing should be a class:

```
class thing(width, height):
    def __init__(width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = <random color logic>
    def getHeight(): return self.height
    def getWidth(): return self.width
    def getColor(): return self.color
```

If you are reusing the rectangles, storing them as classes whose attributes can be called is a better structure.  A rectangle class should know its own width/height/color, while something else keeps track of its location.

Post more code if you want some more help.

Comment: You don't even need the get() functions, but it is a force of habit and enforces a structured access method.

Comment: Python doesn't need `get` type functions, it has `property`s which can do the same thing when needed. However your idea of creating a class to represent the object is a good one, but I would just derive it from [`pygame.Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to avoid having to implement a whole bunch of methods that have already been written.